# sum of matrices with unique solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $K$ be any field with a characteristic, different than 2, and $A$ any $n \times n$-matrix over $K$.

For the equation $A = B + C$, where $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$-matrices over $K$, are $B = \frac{A + A^t}{2}$, $C = \frac{A - A^t}{2}$ the only solutions so that $B$ is symmetric ($B = B^t$) and $C$ is antisymmetric ($C = -C^t$)? And if so, why? And what changes in case that $K$ has characteristic 2?

Thanks. Just a quick question that I need in order to complete another exercise, and that I somehow can't figure out myself.

Comment: in a field of characteristic 2, we can't "divide" by 2, because 2 is not invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $B=B^t$ and $C=-C^t$, then, from $A^t=B^t+C^t$ (because A=B+C) we get that $A^t=B-C$. Add this with $A=B+C$ and obtain: $A+A^t=2B$,so $B=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^t)$. Obviously, $C=\frac{1}{2}(A-A^t)$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$a_{i,j}=b_{i,j}+c_{i,j} ~~~~ (1)$$
and $$a_{j,i}=b_{j,i}+c_{j,i}$$
However $B$ is symmetric and $C$ is antisymmetric, so $$a_{j,i}=b_{i,j}-c_{i,j} ~~~~(2)$$
If we treat $(1), (2)$ as linear equations in $b_{i,j}$ and $c_{i,j}$, we see that they have one solutions whenever we may divide by $2$.  For example, adding the equations we get $a_{i,j}+a_{j,i}=2b_{i,j}$.